# Как удалить связывание объекта?

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net

Доброго времени суток!  Имею связанный с базой  TextBox    `TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataset, "НазваниеТаблицы.НазваниеСтолбца")  Нужно это связывание удалить.  Пишу`BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(TextBox)(строчка из MSDN)  - подчёркивает и сообщает  Name BindingOperations is not declared  Чего хочет?   :(

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Data подключен?
BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(TextBox3);
Только что проверил, все работает.

Comment: Imports System.Windows.Data   на месте.      Про него редактор сообщает 
Namespace or type specified in Imports System.Windows.Data doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found...    и по прежнему его     (BindingOperations.) не признаёт  :((

Comment: Значит не получается получить доступ к этому пространству имен, вероятно поможет доустановка библиотек или переустановка фреймворка. Попробуйте явно подключить сборку, но это костыль